# Is this a valid e-mail " john.doe@hello.example.com"?

Tags: email-validation

I am developing a JavaScript to verify e-mails .

Email comprises of user(name) and address .
Can this address be like " finance.company.com" ?

What is the proper syntax of an e-mail.

Comment: This can just be googled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct e-mail address. There are no restrictions on the number of subdomain levels.